# "Contains" kind of query on Collections using Java 8 Streams API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

we have requirement where we wants to have a autocomplete kind of scenario on our Collections Type.

We have a List of Objects lets say employee. Now the requirement is whenever i type for say "man" it should return me all the employee objects which has "man" in their name and email id.

How can we achieve this in JAVA.I heard about LAMDBA and predicate feature but bot sure how can be use those to our requriment.

Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this.

Comment: `emails.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("man"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
List<Employee> list = ... // Initialize the list.
List<Employee> filterdList = list.stream()
    .filter(emp->emp.getName().contains("man"))
    .filter(emp->emp.getEmail().contains("man"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for the answer.Wanted to check how these two filtered condition will work.?.Whether it will OR and AND Predicate Conditions?.

Comment: It's always an AND. The `filter` method returns a `Stream` with the elements that match the predicate.If you want the elements that match one of the two conditions, you can use `.filter(emp->emp.getName().contains("man") || emp.getEmail().contains("man"))` . Also, the parameter expected by the `filter` method is a `Predicate`, the `Predicate` interface has a [or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or-java.util.function.Predicate-) method if you want to get a composed `Predicate` with the OR of two Predicates.